# Is the normal equation valid over $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis

For reference, the normal equation over $\mathbb{R}^n$ is 
$$\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{X}^T\mathbf{y}$$ and its solution $\mathbf{b}$ represents the optimum solution of the linear equation $\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{y}$ in the minimum norm-difference sense, where $\mathbf{X}$ is a real matrix. A simple proof is just to differentiate the error $\left\Vert\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2=(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{y})^T(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{y})$ with respect to $\mathbf{b}$ and set the result to 0.

So I read a paper recently where they work over $\mathbb{C}^n$ rather than $\mathbb{R}^n$, and they assume that the normal equation still holds true, as 
$$\mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{y},$$
where $\dagger$ represents the matrix adjoint.

At first I thought that a proof of this was just a direct extension of the proof for the real-valued case, but I ran into problems. In particular, the error for complex matrices and vectors is
$$\left\Vert\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{y}\right\Vert^2=(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{y})^\dagger(\mathbf{X}\mathbf{b}-\mathbf{y})=\mathbf{b}^\dagger\mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{Xb}-\mathbf{b}^\dagger\mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{y}^\dagger\mathbf{Xb}+\mathbf{y}^\dagger\mathbf{y}$$
which contains $\mathbf{b}^\dagger$, which as far as I remember from complex analysis is non-holomorphic.

In particular, setting $\mathbf{X}=\mathbf{I}_n$ and $\mathbf{y}=\mathbf{0}$ yields the error $\left\Vert\mathbf{b}\right\Vert^2=\mathbf{b}^\dagger\mathbf{b}=\sum_{i=1}^n|b_i|^2$, which is clearly not holomorphic with respect to complex differentiation by any of the complex variables $b_i$. Does this mean that the standard proof of the normal equation (which proceeds by vector differentiation) fails over $\mathbb{C}^n$ and that a different proof is necessary? If so, how do you prove it over the more general case of $\mathbb{C}^n$?

Unfortunately the Wikipedia page on [least squares minimization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_least_squares_%28mathematics%29) assumes everywhere that minimization is being performed over $\mathbb{R}^n$ rather than $\mathbb{C}^n$, so it's not really useful. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You can differentiate with respect to the real coordinates, or use the Wirtinger derivatives (which amounts to the same, but is more convenient in this form).

Comment: So the theorem remains true, but the proof is more delicate?

Comment: Ok, I found a direct proof on pg. 362 of the 4th edition of Friedberg's "Linear Algebra" that proceeds via inner products rather than complex differentiation, so it's fine.

Comment: I wouldn't even say more delicate. Differentiate with respect to the holomorphic coordinates, you get $$\mathbf{b}^\dagger\mathbf{X}^\dagger\mathbf{X} = \mathbf{y}^\dagger\mathbf{X},$$ with respect to the antiholomorphic coordinates, you get the ${}^\dagger$ed thing.

Comment: Oh, I see. Interesting, thanks.

Comment: And that's using the fact that $\frac{d}{d\mathbf{b}}\mathbf{b}=\mathbf{I}_n$,$\frac{d}{d\mathbf{b}^\dagger} \mathbf{b}=\mathbf{0}_n$ and vice versa, where $\mathbf{0}_n$ is the $n\times n$ zero matrix?

Comment: Right. $$\frac{\partial b_i}{\partial b_j} = \delta_{ij},\; \frac{\partial \overline{b_i}}{\partial b_j} = 0,\; \frac{\partial b_i}{\partial \overline{b_j}} = 0,\; \frac{\partial \overline{b_i}}{\partial\overline{b_j}} = \delta_{ij}.$$