# Optimizing a function over $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: optimization, complex-numbers

I'm trying to find a complex number $c$ that minimizes $\Vert \mathbf{v}-c\mathbf{z}\Vert$ for vectors $\mathbf{v}$ and $\mathbf{z}$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

I guess I'm looking for
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial c} \Vert \mathbf{v}-c\mathbf{z}\Vert = 0$$

The squared norm is easier to deal with, I think. Either way, when you evaluate this, you end up trying to differentiate $\bar{c}$, which of course is meaningless.

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/672451/is-the-normal-equation-valid-over-mathbbcn) covers the general problem. Unfortunately it puts things in terms of holomorphic coordinates, an idea I'm unfamiliar with. There doesn't seem to be a good description of them online either. Wikipedia gets into atlases, charts, and varieties, leading me deeper into a rabbit hole I think probably isn't necessary.

Help?

Comment: $c$ is a complex number, so setting the complex derivative equal to zero isn't what you want. This is an optimization problem in two real variables. You want both the derivative wrt the real part of $c$ and the derivative wrt the complex part of $c$ to be zero.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Squaring the norm gives minimization of 
$$
\|v-cz\|^2=\|v\|^2-2\text{Re}\,\bar{v}^Tcz+|c|^2\|z\|^2.
$$
Write $c=re^{i\theta}$ and minimize the middle term with respect to $e^{i\theta}$ (taking $\theta=-\arg(\bar{v}^Tz)$ will make the real part to be $r|\bar{v}^Tz|$), then use the real $r$ to minimize the quadratic polynomial.

Comment: Great, this gives me $c = \frac{\mathbf{v}^T\bar{\mathbf{z}}}{\Vert\mathbf{z}\Vert^2}$, which looks like the natural analog of the answer with real vectors.

Comment: @MackTuesday One can consider that as a "complex projection" of the vector $v$ on the line $\{cz\}$.